# JAVA_HOME not setting

Tags: java, hadoop, java-home

While working on **Hadoop** Implementation in Pseudo-Distributed Operation, I found following exception of **JAVA_HOME** variable not setting, but When I tried to echo it, it was set.

Variable is preset in `conf/hadoop-env.sh` (edited `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun`), `bash.bashrc`.

```
vardan@vardan-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~/hadoop-0.20.203.0$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
vardan@vardan-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~/hadoop-0.20.203.0$ bin/start-all.sh
starting namenode, logging to /home/vardan/hadoop-0.20.203.0/bin/../logs/hadoop-vardan-namenode-vardan-HP-G62-Notebook-PC.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/vardan/hadoop-0.20.203.0/bin/../logs/hadoop-vardan-datanode-vardan-HP-G62-Notebook-PC.out
localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set. 
localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/vardan/hadoop-0.20.203.0/bin/../logs/hadoop-vardan-secondarynamenode-vardan-HP-G62-Notebook-PC.out
localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set. 
starting jobtracker, logging to /home/vardan/hadoop-0.20.203.0/bin/../logs/hadoop-vardan-jobtracker-vardan-HP-G62-Notebook-PC.out 
localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /home/vardan/hadoop-0.20.203.0/bin/../logs/hadoop-vardan-tasktracker-vardan-HP-G62-Notebook-PC.out
localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.
```

Comment: Please add the lines of `./conf/hadoop-env.sh` in the question if the issue is still unresolved. Also add the lines from the `~/.bashrc` where the path to `JAVA_HOME` is set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if `bin/start-all.sh` doesn't override `JAVA_HOME`

Maybe put `echo $JAVA_HOME` inside that script straight before execution of those binaries?

Comment: Usually startup scripts fire daemons as some other user, so please make sure that this user also has a proper export in .bashrc

Comment: Or manually set java home like given in another answer here, put into bin/start-all.sh:

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun`

Answer (score 4):

I simply added to the ./conf/hadoop-env.sh this line:

```
# The java implementation to use.  Required.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest
```

and it helped

Comment: It's also good to notice that if you already have JAVA_HOME set for some reason (for example because you're using Maven) this can't still be ignored. The JAVA_HOME export still needs to be defined (and not simply with export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME but a proper string).

Comment: Working on Hadoop 1.0.4 from tarball downloaded from Apache. On Ubuntu 12.04 using Open JDK 6 - (ubuntu places the java binary in /usr/bin/java)   so in this file I uncommented the JAVA_HOME variable and replaced it with /usr   and start-all.sh works with no JAVA_HOME error

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me too. Hadoop version is 2.6.0.

Answer (score 3):

The JAVA_HOME variable you set with `set JAVA_HOME=` is relevant only for the current shell. Given that you are starting a new shell when executing `bin/start-all.sh` you need to "export" the environmental variable to make it available in the global scope:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

Answer (score 1):

---

### Installing java 1.6.x

1. Download "jdk-6u32-linux-i586.bin"
2. sh jdk-6u32-linux-i586.bin
3. mv /etc/alternatives/java /etc/alternatives/java_bak
   mv /etc/alternatives/javac /etc/alternatives/javac_bak
4. create link 
   ln -s /opt/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/java /etc/alternatives/java
   ln -s /opt/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/javac /etc/alternatives/javac

5.
  java -version

-----------you must see this --------------------------------
java version "1.6.0_32"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_32-b05)

### Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.7-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write in your .bash_profile file "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun", when you login using a console, either physically at the machine or using ssh, .bash_profile is executed., .bashrc is open when you execute /bin/bash or another terminal

you can also try to write it inside the start-all.sh

make sure that JAVA_HOME has the correct path

Answer (score 0):

same problem on Ubuntu Precise + CDH4...

long story short, CDH4 uses bigtop and the simplest way to set JAVA_HOME is to edit the /etc/default/bigtop-utils file such as:

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_43/jre/

Note: I couldn't find any hadoop-env.sh file following a proper CDH4 install.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the scripts that initializes dfs and mapreduce daemons do not have JAVA_HOME defined in its environment.
Posibly, when executing HDFS and MapReduce, its execution environment is the one specified by the script $HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh. Consequently, it would be enough to define JAVA_HOME at $HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh :

```
export JAVA_HOME=jdk-home-path
```

Otherwise, when this is not enough, the problem may be that the configuration environment used (hadoop-env.sh) is not the one we are expecting; hadoop is choosing another one or the default value if none found. The fastest solution will be defining the conf directory where the hadoop-env.sh script is placed. Setting the HADOOP_CONF_DIR environment variable will be enough:

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=hadoop-home-path/conf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your `.bashrc` file:

> export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")

and it will dynamically change when you update your packages and get used by Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to check $JAVA_HOME configuration as below:
1. for `hadoop-1.x`: hadoop-home-path/conf/hadoop-env.sh
2. for `hadoop-2.x`: hadoop-home-path/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh