# setting JAVA_HOME in linux

Tags: java, linux, hadoop

i set java_home:

```
#echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk
```

but when i have this error in running hadoop:

```
localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.
```

**EDIT**
I set `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk` on start-all.sh but not workeed

```
# The java implementation to use.
#export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk
# The jsvc implementation to use. Jsvc is required to run secure datanodes.
#export JSVC_HOME=${JSVC_HOME}

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-"/etc/hadoop"}

# Extra Java CLASSPATH elements.  Automatically insert capacity-scheduler.
for f in $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar; do
  if [ "$HADOOP_CLASSPATH" ]; then
    export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$f
  else
    export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$f
  fi
done
# The maximum amount of heap to use, in MB. Default is 1000.
#export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=
#export HADOOP_NAMENODE_INIT_HEAPSIZE=""

# Extra Java runtime options.  Empty by default.
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

# Command specific options appended to HADOOP_OPTS when specified
export HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-Dhadoop.security.logger=${HADOOP_SECURITY_LOGGER:-INFO,RFAS} -Dhdfs.audit.logger=${HDFS_AUDIT_LOGGER:-INFO,NullAppender} $HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS="-Dhadoop.security.logger=ERROR,RFAS $HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS"

export HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS="-Dhadoop.security.logger=${HADOOP_SECURITY_LOGGER:-INFO,RFAS} -Dhdfs.audit.logger=${HDFS_AUDIT_LOGGER:-INFO,NullAppender} $HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS"

# The following applies to multiple commands (fs, dfs, fsck, distcp etc)
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xmx512m $HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS"
#HADOOP_JAVA_PLATFORM_OPTS="-XX:-UsePerfData $HADOOP_JAVA_PLATFORM_OPTS"

# On secure datanodes, user to run the datanode as after dropping privileges
export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER=${HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER}

# Where log files are stored.  $HADOOP_HOME/logs by default.
#export HADOOP_LOG_DIR=${HADOOP_LOG_DIR}/$USER

# Where log files are stored in the secure data environment.
export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_LOG_DIR=${HADOOP_LOG_DIR}/${HADOOP_HDFS_USER}

# The directory where pid files are stored. /tmp by default.
# NOTE: this should be set to a directory that can only be written to by 
#       the user that will run the hadoop daemons.  Otherwise there is the
#       potential for a symlink attack.
export HADOOP_PID_DIR=${HADOOP_PID_DIR}
export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_PID_DIR=${HADOOP_PID_DIR}

# A string representing this instance of hadoop. $USER by default.
export HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=$USER
```

**EDIT2**

I edit `hadoop-env.sh` file and set java folder but not working yet

Comment: R U sure that Hadoop is running under the same user environment?

Comment: Try `update-java-alternatives -l` and `update-java-alternatives -s`.

Comment: @AlexR , I run them in one terminal

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `update-java-alternatives: command not found`

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: I had to set it in hadoop-env.sh too for hadoop to pick it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the environment variable is not visible to hadoop. You can make it global e.g. by modifying the .bashrc script or simply setting the environment variable where hadoop can see it.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to set JAVA_HOME in `hadoop-env.sh` to the same directory as well if you have not already done so

also this question might be help. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192823/java-home-not-setting?rq=1)

Comment: can you post the content of `hadoop-env.sh`?

Comment: is this a local, psuedo-distributed, or physically-distributed cluster?

Comment: if this is local you should not be executing the start-all.sh script