# JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME does not work in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, java-home

when i try hadoop2.x,I start a Pseudo-Distributed Operetion ,when I type "sbin/start-dfs.sh",I got a error:
   JAVA_HOME is not exist
then I check the etc/hadoop/hadoop-ennv.sh ,I find a line "JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME",and I have already set the JAVA_HOME in /etc/profile.
i can't figure out why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAVA\_HOME not setting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192823/java-home-not-setting)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to set JAVA_HOME in  "yarn-env.sh" for hadoop 2.x 
This file can be found on the same path where you can see hadoop-env.sh under /etc/hadoop